# tintColor on motion xml in as3 doesn't work

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash

I wrote this motion xml inside my as3 code:

```
public function moveMe(e:Event)
        {
            var myXml = 
            <Motion duration="10">
                <source>
                    <Source>
                    </Source>
                </source>
                <Keyframe index="0">
                    <tweens>
                        <SimpleEase />
                    </tweens>
                </Keyframe>
                    <color>
                        <Color tintColor="0x950F1B" tintMultiplier="1"/>
                    </color>
                <Keyframe index="30" x="50" y="30" scaleX="1.1" scaleY="0.9" rotatin="21"/>
            </Motion>;

            myAnimator = new Animator(myXml, mySubject);
            myAnimator.play();
        }
```

the movement and scale change work great but the color doesn't change and i don't know why.
thanks!

Comment: May be tr to pass it in this format: `"#950F1B"`

Comment: Hi Cherniv, tnx for the editing and the answer. Unfortaintly, it still doesn't work.

Comment: You're welcome! Is it working now?

Comment: No :( I don't understand why...